# Success Notification XML in 2009 is not read by transport service in 2013

Tags: 2013, publishing, 2009, transport

We are in middle of upgrading the CMS from 2009 to 2013 SP1.

As part of staged upgrade, We are trying to publish from 2013 sp1 CMS to 2009 Deployer.

In this process the content published successfully. But the success message is not returned to the CMS server.

After some observations came to know that Notification XML is not read by the Transporter service. It is lying under Incoming work directory forever, unlike new target (where Tridion 2013 deployer, where it is read by transport service and reflecting status in queue correctly).

Cd_transport.log reads :

`INFO  MetaInfo - Could not read destination metadata, assuming unlimited window size ERROR HTTPSTransportConnector - Batch could not be read, no notification data could be loaded`

while cd_core.log reads :

> ERROR JAXBUtil - Unmarshalling failed. org.xml.sax.SAXParseException:
>   Content is not allowed in prolog.     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown
>   Source) ~[na:1.7.0_51]    at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown
>   Source) ~[na:1.7.0_51]    at
>   com.tridion.util.JAXBUtil.unmarshalFromString(JAXBUtil.java:176)
>   ~[cd_core.jar:na]     at
>   com.tridion.transport.connection.connectors.HTTPSTransportConnector.batchRetrieve(HTTPSTransportConnector.java:290)
>   [cd_transport.jar:na]     at
>   com.tridion.transport.connection.connectors.TransportPoolConnector.batchRetrieve(TransportPoolConnector.java:85)
>   [cd_transport.jar:na]     at
>   com.tridion.transport.DestinationController.poll(DestinationController.java:260)
>   [cd_transport.jar:na]     at
>   com.tridion.transport.DestinationController.run(DestinationController.java:221)
>   [cd_transport.jar:na]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   [na:1.7.0_51]

After waiting for long time in Waiting for Deployment/Deploying status, subsequently publishing queue shows up status as "failed"

> Polling for notification for destination has exceeded polling attempts
>   for transaction

Any clue what could be missing here?

Anything to do with window size?
We are unable to locate Winodows size parameter in cd_deployer.xml in 2009 deployer?

Answer (score 7):

"JAXBUtil - Unmarshalling failed" means that the XML file was not able to be parsed (deserialized).  This typically happens when the java class(es) mapped to the Xml elements don't match up.

This seems logical because transport/deployer mechanism was seriously updated/changed from 2009 to 2013.  And I don't believe this is an officially supported scenario anyway.

I've seen Tridion 2011 (sort of) work with the 2009 Deployer, but there were quirks when it came to status messages and we ended up upgrading the Deployer too (in the end it became less hassle to do this than to try and hack 2011 with an older version).

It would be logical to expect (with 2013's Undo functionality and other optimizations) to have 2009 and 2013 even less compatible than 2009 and 2011.  I suggest reconsidering the staged approach and upgrading both sides, CM and CD.

Comment: The "mixed upgrade" scenarios supported are the other way around - CD first, CM later. You can publish from Tridion 2009 to a Tridion 2013 Deployer, but not the reverse. Also... we typically only support this mixed versions scenario for 1 version, not more... I do know it happens to work with 2009/2013, but this is not guaranteed to be the case in the future.

Comment: BTW, this "staged upgrade" process is described in the documentation: http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-2DF1AFF7-40C1-46E5-BA7B-5768B0544FA6